# Check to see if email is enabled?

Tags: iphone, email

I'm working on an iPhone app that, at a certain point, will try to send an email message. If the user has an email set up, great, if not, I need to change some actions accordingly. My question is how do I check to see if the user's iPhone has an email account setup? I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find an answer.

I'm using MFMailViewController to send the message, but I don't want to create an instance of it unless I can actually send something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MFMailComposeViewController class has `+canSendMail` method which

> Returns a Boolean indicating whether
>   the current device is able to send
>   email. (YES if the device is configured for sending email or NO if it is not.)

Comment: I saw this, but didn't realize it was a class method til I saw your reply. Thanks a lot!